# Removing activex from html

Tags: php, html, string, parsing, activex

I have a php script that I am trying to write. The script is suppose to open a html file as a string and parse the string for the tags  . I would like to remove everything between the object tags as well as the tags them self. Once done parsing id like it to save the file. Here is the code I have so far.

```
<?php
$handle = file_get_contents("index.htm", "r");
#$str = preg_replace("/<object[0-9 a-z_?*&=\":\-\/\.#\,<>\\n\\r\\t]+<\/object>/smi", "", >             $str);
strip_tags("<object>", "</object>")
print "$handle"
?>
```

Comment: You could have a look at HTMLPurifier. http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Don't use regexes. You'll just end up completely mangling your document. Removal of a tag and its contents are trivial using [DOM](http://php.net/dom)

Comment: I will take a look into both methods. Thanks guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is code

```
             include './simple_html_dom.php';
            // replace this url with your file url
            $file = "http://localhost:8012/PhpProject1/file.html";
            $html = file_get_html($file);
            foreach($html->find('object') as $element) 
            {
                            $element->outertext = '';
            }
            // this is your html without Object tags 
            echo $html;
```

Download library from [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simple_html_dom.php/download)

hope it will work

Comment: Works well but how do I overwrite the existing file with the new output ?

Comment: just simple php filing @Dk6861636b